# iOS 4 create pie chart from 1 UIView and background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiview, calayer

I know that UIViews may transforms have applied to them , some of which change the shape of the underlying layer.

Here's what I want to do: **Create one circular UIView**, superimpose it on a different color background and **cut a section from the UIView's middle over to it's edge, in an arc.**

Is this possible with iOS?

Comment: See `Graphics and Drawing in iOS` in the xcode help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This dude made an awesome class for drawing pie charts:

http://code.google.com/p/chartreuse/downloads/detail?name=chartreuse-v1.0.zip&can=2&q=